# How do I tell org-mode to disable headings in verbatim text?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

How do I make org mode not interpret a line that begins with an asterisk as a headline?  I have some verbatim text in my org mode document.  Some of the lines begin with an asterisk.  Org mode interprets these lines as headlines.  I don't want that.

Here is the text with some context:

```
    * 20160721 Headline for July 21, 2016

    I created a git repository for rfc-tools.  It's in
    ~/Documents/rfc-tools.

    Renamed grep-rfc-index.sh to search-rfc-index.sh because it searches.
    That it uses grep is irrelevant.

    Wrote a README.md for the project.  Here it is:

    #+BEGIN_SRC text
    ----- BEGIN QUOTED TEXT -----
    This is the README.md for rfc-tools, a collection of programs for
    processing IETF RFCs.

    * fetch-rfcs-by-title.sh downloads into the current directory the RFCs
      whose titles contain the string given on the command line.  Uses an
      rfc-index file in the current directory.  Prefers the PDF version of
      RFCs but will obtain the text version if the PDF is not available.

    * fetch-sip-rfcs.sh downloads RFCs that contain "Session Initiation"
      in their titles into the current directory.

    * search-rfc-index.sh searches an rfc-index file in the current
      directory for the string given on the command line.  The string can
      contain spaces.

    * join-titles.awk turns the contents of an rfc-index file into a
      series of long lines.  Each line begins with the RFC number, then a
      space, then the rest of the entry from the rfc-index.
    ----- END QUOTED TEXT -----
    #+END_SRC
```

I want the lines between "----- BEGIN QUOTED TEXT -----" and "----- END QUOTED TEXT -----" to be plain text and subordinate to the headline "20160721 Headline for July 21, 2016".  Org mode interprets all lines that begin with an asterisk as top-level headlines.

By the way, the verbatim text is Markdown.  I hope that doesn't matter.

Comment: A better title for this question is "How do I tell org-mode to disable headings in verbatim text"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

worked for me:

```
    #+BEGIN_SRC markdown
```

Comment: add some more details to your answer

Comment: That's a third of the answer.  First, install and load markdown-mode.el.  Second, prepend  a space to each line of the markdown code.  Now you can invoke markdown-mode on the text with C-c '.  Exit markdown-mode with another C-c '.  Everything in the markdown source block is correctly formatted for org-mode.

Comment: The space prepending trick also works for #+BEGIN_SRC text ... #+END_SRC

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping your text in one of the various special block tags. For example you could try putting your text inside these tags:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC text

...

#+END_SRC
```

Here is a screenshot of how the formatting turns out on my Emacs:

[image]

If that doesn't meet your needs, you could try:

```
 #+BEGIN_EXAMPLE

 ...

 #+END_EXAMPLE
```

Which will render everything inside the tags without markup and in a monospace font.

If that doesn't work either, you could try one of the other kinds of tags listed [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Easy-Templates.html).

Comment: I've tried all that.  Neither BEGIN_SRC nor BEGIN_EXAMPLE nor BEGIN_QUOTE nor BEGIN_VERSE turn off the special nature of the leading asterisk in the text I'm quoting.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. That is strange. This may be an interaction with some other org-related settings in your `.emacs`. You might try to see if it works when you start Emacs with the `-Q` option. See my screenshot for how it worked for me.

Comment: What happens when you press TAB on the headline "20160721 Headline for July 21, 2016"?  When I do as you described, above, org-mode hides the text between that line and "* fetch-rfcs-by-title.sh downloads into the current directory the RFCs".  I want to hide all of the text through "#+END_SRC"

Comment: In other words, org-mode treats "* fetch-rfcs-by-title.sh downloads into the current directory the RFCs" as a headline.  If I press TAB on that line, org-mode hides everything up to the next line that begins with an asterisk, "* fetch-sip-rfcs.sh downloads RFCs that contain "Session Initiation""

Comment: Yes, I didn't realize it until you mentioned it, but I get the same behavior. The only way I have found around this so far, is to make sure that those bullets are indented a level deeper than your headline, but then they are still acting "special", they are just nested under another headline.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the * with a comma like this,*

Probably if you type C-c ' to enter a special edit and then exit, org will do that for you.

Comment: That definitely turns off the special meaning of "*" but it also changes the text I want to include verbatim.

Comment: I tried C-c ' and emacs responded, "No special environment to edit here".

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is "You can't do that".  I found a way to work around the problem using drawers.  The [org-mode manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Drawers.html#Drawers) explains that a drawer is a place to put text that you don't want to see all of the time.

A StackExchange user had a question about 
[getting a custom org drawer to open/close](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16511/how-can-i-get-a-custom-org-drawer-to-open-close).  It seems that for older versions of org-mode, you must tell org-mode the names of your drawers.  E.g. If you have a drawer named "COMMANDS"

```
:COMMANDS:
ls
cat
grep
:END:
```

you must tell org-mode the name of the drawer using the +DRAWERS keyword:

```
#+DRAWERS COMMAND
```

and restart org-mode.

Comment: While this will work, a better answer is to prepend a space to each line of the text that confuses org-mode, then surround the text with #+BEGIN_SRC text ... #+END_SRC.  In my case, with markdown text, I used #+BEGIN_SRC markdown ... #+END_SRC.  Once you have the leading space on each line, org-mode doesn't confuse your text for its own and you can edit it with C-c '.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

1. Escape Character

You may sometimes want to write text that looks like Org syntax, but should really read as plain text.  Org may use a specific escape character in some situations, i.e., a backslash in macros (see Macro Replacement) and links (see Link Format), or a comma in source and example blocks (see Literal Examples).  In the general case, however, we suggest to use the zero width space.  You can insert one with any of the following:

C-x 8  zero width space

C-x 8  200B

For example, in order to write ‘[[1,2]]’ as-is in your document, you may write instead

[X[1,2]]

where ‘X’ denotes the zero width space character.

2. How to remove zero width space:

sed -i "s/$(echo -ne '\u200b')//g"  abc.txt